# How do I send a function to a parent to be then use it inside the child?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the following coding behaviour :

```
addAssetsTab(false, false, false).action = addAssetAction;
```

The function addAssetsTab would return an object with a function called action inside, I want then to set that function to something in my current scope and I want the child to use it once action gets called.

```
var tabs = [];
addPeopleTab = function (filter, sort, viewModes) {
                    var promise = { action: function () { } };
                    tabs.push(
                    angular.extend({}, DataTemplates.headerContextualTab, {
                        id: 'people',
                        label: 'People',
                        classes: 'icon-group',
                        count: 0,
                        action: promise.action,
                        filter: filter,
                        sort: sort,
                        viewModes: viewModes
                    }))
                    return promise;
                };
```

Apparently for some reason once I return that object called promise, the reference to the local object called promise gets lost..I tried returning a function but the reference will also get lost..any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how you return the `promise`, or set the `promise.action`; it's how you *pass* the `promise.action` function to `angular.extend`; you're passing the *function reference*, so when you *later update* `promise.action` (to point to a new function reference), your extended object is still pointing to the old function reference.

Instead, you could do something like this;

```
angular.extend({}, DataTemplates.headerContextualTab, {
    id: 'people',
    label: 'People',
    classes: 'icon-group',
    count: 0,
    action: function () {
        return promise.action.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    filter: filter,
    sort: sort,
    viewModes: viewModes
}));
```

This way, as it holds a reference to `promise` instead, it will always be able to resolve to the *current* value of `promise.action`. Using [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) lets you forward the arguments passed to the `action` method to the `promise.action` method.

Comment: I understand now, you pass the reference to the current promise because you did not resolve the value of action by wrapping it around an anonymous function :) . Darns! How did I Not thought of it before haha, thanks :)